# how can i keep the current use logged in with Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

i am new in laravel and i am developing an application to manage rooms reservation..
after the user log in and redirected to the home page i tested `dd(Auth::check())` and it gives me `True`, but in the home page the user must choose a date and click search to search for empty rooms at that specific date, the problem is that after calling any other function `dd(Auth::check())` always gives me `False`.
what should i do?

[here is the login function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y3Ze.png)

[in the home page the user should choose a date then a function called showEmptyRooms will be called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjBAw.png)

[and here is the function showEmptyRooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOvcx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Auth in routes? People should be able to go to the logged route when they pass the auth test in middleware.